# how to post to user's wall using facebook button?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-sharer

I need a way to post message in user's wall using facebook button. I tried using facebook share button, but it is now deprecated and the "message" field in api is also deprecated.
Do anyone know a way to do that? 
Note I want to that using javascript.
any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the offered [Social Plugins](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/)? Would one of these help you? The [send button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/send/) perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

The sharer.php plugin (that you described) has been deprecated.

The best way to do this now is by using the Facebook Graph API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/